# how to avoid firefox "opening" dialog for blocked content?

Tags: firefox

I use firefox for browsing at work. IS of the company blocks couple of websites including facebook. So, every website uses facebook connect or put facebook "like" button shows this dialog:

[image: the annoying dialog]

This dialog opens 2 or 3 times every time I browse to page uses facebook or any blocked content.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work-around you can do any of :

- Install [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) and block fbcdn.net.
- Add "||facebook.com^$third-party" to your Adblock-plus filters
- Open your hosts file (%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts in windows7) and add "127.0.0.1 fbcdn.net" to block all connections to it.

Comment: I used the adblock-plus method (already installed) and it works :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be that your proxy properly set the Content-Type to html. Without that, firefox considers the resource as a binary, and can do nothing else than offering to download it.

As a workaround, you can check the "Do this automatically..." so that the dialog box is not shown.

Comment: +1 for the proxy solution. But I don't have control on this proxy. Can't use it. by the way, "Do this automatically..." removes the opening dialog but added "Save as" dialog :D